# Why is a container parameter used in a priority queue for overloading?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, c++14, priority-queue

```
std::priority_queue< int, std::vector<int>, std::greater<int> > pq;
```

Why is the *vector* parameter used?

Comment: What is your question exactly? Why it's `std::vector`, or why there's a container parameter at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The priority queue implementation can use different types of containers to build the underlining data structure. You can specify which one you like the most using that template parameter.
- Quoting from [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue)

  > Container -   The type of the underlying container to use to store the
  >   elements. The container must satisfy the requirements of
  >   SequenceContainer, and its iterators must satisfy the requirements of
  >   RandomAccessIterator. Additionally, it must provide the following
  >   functions with the usual semantics:
  >       front()
  >       push_back()
  >       pop_back()
  >       The standard containers std::vector and std::deque satisfy these requirements.

Btw, `vector` is the default one.